# How can I pass an instance to a ServiceInjector trait with scala?

Tags: scala, guice

I'm following the advice from com.googlegroups.google-guice http://markmail.org/message/ljnhl6rstverrxuj

```
Well, it's actually almost as referred to you in the link from the other answer:

http://jonasboner.com/2008/10/06/real-world-scala-dependency-injection-di/

class MyClient {
  @Inject val toBeInjected: AnotherClass = toBeInjected // !!
}

trait ServiceInjector {
  ServiceInjector.inject( this )
}

object ServiceInjector {
  private val injector = Guice.createInjector( Array[Module]( new YourModule ) )
  def inject( obj: AnyRef ) = injector.injectMembers( obj )
}

Usage:

val client = new MyClient with ServiceInjector

or:

class InjectedMyClient extends MyClient with ServiceInjector
```

But I'm very new to Scala and trying to work out how I can use the following pattern for dependency injection, when the Guice Module itself needs references to instances passed in from elsewhere.

But since traits can't have constructors, and neither can the Companion Object it looks like I'm screwed?

```
package au.id.rleach.overmind.guice

import com.google.inject.{Provides, Guice, Binder, Module}
import org.slf4j.Logger
import org.spongepowered.api.service.ServiceManager
import org.spongepowered.api.world.TeleportHelper
import org.spongepowered.api.{GameRegistry, Game}
import org.spongepowered.api.plugin.PluginManager
import org.spongepowered.api.scoreboard.ScoreboardBuilder
import org.spongepowered.api.service.event.EventManager

class OModule(val game: Game, val logger: Logger, val pluginManager: PluginManager, val serviceManager: ServiceManager, val eventManager: EventManager, val gameRegistry: GameRegistry, val teleportHelper: TeleportHelper) extends Module {

  override def configure(binder: Binder): Unit = {
    binder.bind(classOf[Game]).toInstance(game)
    binder.bind(classOf[Logger]).toInstance(logger)
    binder.bind(classOf[PluginManager]).toInstance(pluginManager)
    binder.bind(classOf[ServiceManager]).toInstance(serviceManager)
    binder.bind(classOf[EventManager]).toInstance(eventManager)
    binder.bind(classOf[GameRegistry]).toInstance(gameRegistry)
    binder.bind(classOf[TeleportHelper]).toInstance(teleportHelper)
    //bind(classOf[File]).annotatedWith(new ConfigDirAnnotation(true)).toInstance(Loader.instance.getConfigDir)
  }
}

trait ServiceInjector {
  ServiceInjector.inject(this)
}

object ServiceInjector {
  private val injector = Guice.createInjector(
//####
    new OModule()//compilation error.
//####
  )
  def inject(obj: AnyRef) = injector.injectMembers(obj)
}
```

I realize that the object is being initialized when it's first used, and that is after I have a copy of the instances to pass to OModule, but I can't seem to find a way to pass them in to the object.

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm using Scala I am not a fan anymore of using DI frameworks since Scala has natively DI-like support already. This is called the Cake Pattern. There are plenty resources available on this, like this [blogpost from Cake Solutions](http://www.cakesolutions.net/teamblogs/2011/12/19/cake-pattern-in-depth).

Both at ScalaDays 2014 and Devoxx 2014 Dick Wall also presented about a more lightweight DI solution which he called the Parfait Pattern. Both talks can be viewed on Parleys.com

If you really want to use a DI framework, Scaldi is a nice looking Scala framework utilising Scala features, but of course you can also keep on using Spring or Guice.

Comment: The reason why I'm using Guice is for Java compatibility, and I'm getting instances already via guice injection from SpongeAPI, the minecraft server mod.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about this:

```
@Inject val toBeInjected: AnotherClass = toBeInjected
```

wouldn't work in my experience.  It needs to be a `var` rather than `val` and the initial value `null`.

```
@Inject var toBeInjected: AnotherClass = null
```

I created a [demo on GitHub](https://github.com/bjfletcher/play-inject-field-example) which is the `Play-Scala` template with the `index` method changed as follows:

```
class Application extends Controller {

  @Inject var ws: WSClient = null

  def index = Action.async {
    ws.url("http://google.com").get.map(r => Ok(r.body))
  }

}
```

which worked well. That injected to a field, rather than as a constructor parameter. The same technique can be used with `traits`.

Comment: Injecting val's works fine, that isn't the part I was having issues with.

The problem was that I couldn't pass in the instances that the module needs, and I don't have access to the injector that is used to obtain the instances in the plugin class.

I ended up creating a setter for the module in the object, but I don't really like that solution either so was hoping something better got posted on stack overflow.

Comment: `@Inject val toBeInjected: AnotherClass = toBeInjected` <- what is `toBeInjected` here? Why have `@Inject` if you're going to get the injector and inject it yourself instead?